# How is better technique to retrieve data from database within html structure between retrieve only data in database using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I've planning to build an website which mostly work with **Ajax** but I concern about the speed of my PHP code structure.

**First technique**

I've initial all data values which I query from DB and combine with HTMl, CSS selector to a variable in my method and then echo it out to the client browser as below function.

Both of this techniques I've using Ajax to respond all data but for this method I will using Ajax **dataType** as **HTML** because my PHP echo with client side script.

```
public function last_update() {

    $this->select_cat = $this->select_cats('tmv');
    $out = '';
    $out .= '<div class="soc"><div class="sr"><div class="s"><span class="">Newest and Last update</span></div></div></div><div id = "cat_menu2" class = "owl-carousel owl-theme">';
    foreach ($this->select_cat as $k => $cat_val) {
        if ($cat_val) {
            $out .= '<div style = "border-right:1px solid rgba(69, 69, 69, 0.48);"><div class = "row mi"><a>Hello man dfds dfgdfg </a></div></div>';
        } else {
            $out .= '<div style = "border-right:1px solid rgba(69, 69, 69, 0.48);"><div class = "row mi"><a>Hello man dfds dfgdfg </a></div></div>';
        }
    }
    $out .= '</div>';
    return $out;
}
```

**Second technique**

**Another hand**, I though how it is difference if I using javascript with Ajax method to query only data from database after I got all data I will using Javascript, CSS, HTM, to make up or make the layout for client view.

```
    <script>
    $(window).ready(function () {

        var prodId = '', prodName = '', prodPrice = '', prodImg = '', prodSImg = '';
        var data_array = [];
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "<?php echo base_url('main/fuck'); ?>",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function (data, st) {
                if (st == 'success') {
                    $.each(data.data, function (i, obj) {
                        obj = {
                            prodId: obj.prodId,
                            prodName: obj.prodName,
                            prodPrice: obj.prodPrice,
                            prodImg: obj.prodImg,
                            prodSImg: obj.prodSImg,
                        }
                        data_array.push(obj);
                    });
                }
                console.log(data_array); // I will using html,css to make up or create layout of my task here and then append to some elements 
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with AJAX, one thing that we should keep in mind is **Keep everything lightweight**.

Which means, any data that are not really necessary or can be processed on the client side should be omitted and do it on the client side.

It is not a good practice to include any html code in your ajax response it will just make your response very bloated. So instead, it is better to just output the raw data which could be in JSON format and processed after using Javascript.

In your part, the **second technique** you mentioned is more preferable than the first.

Example:

JSON Response(sample.php):

```
[{
    name: "Hello",
    age: 18
},
{
    name: "World",
    age: 21
}]
```

JavaScript(jQuery):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:  "sample.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {

        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            var $con = $("<div>");

            // name
            var $name = $("<div>");
            $name.html(data[i].name);

            // age
            var $age = $("<div>");
            $age.html(data[i].age);

            $("#user").append($con);

            $con.append($name);
            $con.append($age);

        }

    }
})
```

HTML:

```
<div id="user">
</div>
```

Comment: If second technique is good should you guild me some thing for make a better than this? How is it good or not if I combine HTML and CSS into Javascript and using some method of Jquery to make the layout?

Comment: And as you can see, I didn't use jQuery $.each() for iterating the array, because it is slow.

Comment: Ok thanks I will test it how ever I don't know any compiler which easy to valid my website or my code structure is faster or good

Comment: Google has an online tool for that :) https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/